# If my Lambda function is triggered by kinesis streams events, will it autoscale?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Lambda function, which is listening to multiple kinesis streams events. If this Lambda function is busy processing records from one of the subscribed kinesis stream and there are records waiting to be processed in other subscribed kinesis streams, then will AWS spin out more instances of this Lambda function (in Docker) to serve all the data records in all the subscribed kinesis streams?

Comment: Have you read through this?
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/scaling.html

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for the information. So as per this page 
Stream-based event sources for Lambda functions that process Kinesis or DynamoDB streams the number of shards is the unit of concurrency. If your stream has 100 active shards, there will be at most 100 Lambda function invocations running concurrently. This is because Lambda processes each shard’s events in sequence.

That answer one part of my question. What if the Lambda is subscribed to multiple kinesis streams (lets say 3) (each with one shard). Will there be 3 concurrent instances of Lambda function running?

Comment: I would say yes, Lambda's designed to scale up like that. You can easily give it a test by having your lambda sleep for X seconds, and time how long it takes to process Y simultaneous requests. You should see a total time less than X * Y.